# Python binding for ZeroMQ versions later than 3.0

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I am basically looking for ZeroMQ Python binding sample examples, where I can explore and experiment. I am particularly interested in xsub. xpub examples where we have publishers and subscriber joining and leaving notifications.

I could find a 2.1 version binding and an example, but what I understand is that xsub is supported only for versions greater than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current PyZMQ (≥ 2.1.7) works with all versions of libzmq after 2.1.4, including 3.1-dev.  Simply build/install libzmq-3.1, and then build/install pyzmq (possibly instructing pyzmq about libzmq's installation location), and you will be using zmq3 with Python.  This is clearly stated in [the pyzmq readme](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq).

Comment: It's a bit annoying that the bundled pyzmq-static is still on zeromq2 and that homebrew installing still defaults to zeromq2 too. Anything going to happen to kick the ecosystem to the next version?

Comment: I imagine they will update when there is an actual release of libzmq3.  There still has yet to be a first libzmq3 stable release (only RC so far).  Just do `brew install --HEAD zeromq && pip install pyzmq`, and you should be set.